# Jquery event condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two DIV , what I want to do is :

- if I hover on div1 => div2 show
- if mouse left from div1 **and** div2 => div2 hide
- if mouse left from div1 but it's still on div2 => div2 show
- By default div2 => hide

I tried :

```
 $("#div1,.div2").mouseleave(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".popover").css("display", "none");
    }, 2000);
});
```

But when I left from div1 and keep mouse on div2, 2000s more, div2 is hided.

How to write the 3rd condition in jquery event please.

Thanks.

Comment: provide you html code. Because your explanation is confusing

Comment: can you post your markup for this?

Comment: are you expecting the result like this http://jsfiddle.net/XjAde/ ?

Comment: @Beginner, I want `<div class="div2"> two </div>` still show even the mouse leave from `<div id="div1"> first </div>` in your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another event called `mouseenter` on `div2` which would then be able to cancel any timeout created in `div1` or `div2`; Note for sake of clarity I am referencing by ID in the selectors below as you seem to have an ID for `div1` and a class for `div2`

```
$("#div1,#div2").mouseleave(function(){
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $("#div2").css("display", "none");
    }, 2000);
});

$("#div2").mouseenter(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

Comment: The second event (mouseenter) did not work. Still giving same error as mine.

Comment: I can not set `$("#div2").css("display", "block");` and `#div2{display:none;}` in your css due to the condition of the css in my project.

Comment: Then what are the constraints?  Give us more of your code, i.e. is div2 inside of div1 or not?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bobkhin/4Ldfs/ , but `display:block` in #dropdown-menu and `display: none;` in class="popover are omitted.

Comment: Sorry, that fiddle doesn't work.  It has errors.  I also don't understand your last comment?  How does that fiddle relate at all to what the question is?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47246/discussion-between-domo-and-rob-schmuecker)

Answer (score 0):

You have to cancel the pending timeout when the cursor enters div2:

```
var timer;
$("#div1,.div2").mouseleave(function(){
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $(".div2").css("display", "none");
    }, 2000);
});

$(".div2").mouseenter(function(){
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

As soon as the cursor leaves div2, the corresponding mouseleave callback is called and the timer starts again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**HTML code:**

```
<div class='div1'>Div One
    <div class='div2'>Div Two</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
$('.div1')
.mouseover(function(){
    $('.div2').fadeIn();
})
.mouseleave(function(){
    $('.div2').fadeOut();
})
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Vmq8h/

Comment: div1 and div2 are not next to each other, so if I do that, I cannot go to div2 if the mouse left from div1.

Comment: I think when you will goto div2 after leaving from div1, div2 is visible. But when you leave mouse from div2 it's get invisible. check example again. http://jsfiddle.net/Vmq8h/

Comment: I meant, if div1 is far from div2 20px so I can not hover on div2, because it's already invisible while I left the mouse from div1.

Comment: for that you have to play with css and more elements.

Comment: Any sample example about that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it. Although I am not sure if it is proper:

```
$("#div1").mouseleave(function(e){
   if(!$(e.target).parents(".div2")){
      setTimeout(function(){
        $(".popover").css("display", "none");
      }, 2000);
  }
```

});

Here I check that on mouseleave if the event parent is not div2.(Means if the mouse is not in div2) as per the if condition, then only we closr the popover.

Comment: When the mouse left from div1 and div2, div2 still shows with this solution.

Comment: ok. As per my understanding, you moved from div1 to div2 and then out.If this is the case, put a class on both the divs and then write the event using that class. replace #div1 with .someCommonClass. Please provide more details otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with css:

```
.div2{
 visibility: hidden;
}

.div1:hover .div2{
 visibility:visible;
}

.div2:hover{
 visibility:visible;
}
```

Comment: div1 and div2 are not next to each other, so if I do that, I cannot go to div2 if the mouse left from div1.